# Поднятие сипа в астериск

Tags: asterisk, sip

Зарегил сип в задарме,поднимаю его в астериске,показывает что сип поднят все хорошо,но дозвониться не могу,в задарме в личном кабинете показывает что сип оффлайн,хотя в астере показывает что все хорошо,и даже если в астере меняю какой то любой пароль который не совпадает,всеравно пишет что сип поднят.В чем дело подскажите пожалуйста

```
register => 622317:XXXXXXX@sip.zadarma.com/622317

[622317]
context=general
type=friend
username=622317
secret=XXXXXXX
qualify=yes
host=sip.zadarma.com
dtmfmode=rfc2833
relaxdtmf=yes
nat=yes
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
insecure=invite
fromuser=622317
canreinvite=no


Name/username             Host                                    Dyn Forcerport ACL Port     Status
622317/622317             185.45.152.174                               N             5060     OK (46 ms)
```

Comment: Клуб анонимных гадалок, чем Вам помочь?

Comment: Ну например сказать почему астер все время показывает что сип онлайн,хотя это не так.

Comment: Спрятали бы пароль реальный, за это время уже с вашего акка можно было звонков наделать кучу

Comment: аккаунт бесплатный) так что не страшно

Comment: какой бы пароль не ставил астер всегда показывает статус онлайн,не понимаю в чем дело

Comment: Регистрация проходит, ошибках в консоли астера нет по этому поводу? 
У вас qualify=yes вот Status ОК и пишет (хост 185.45.152.174 доступен, отвечает на запросы), а то, что звонки не проходят, нужно посмотреть что приходит в ответном пакете от провайдера при отбое.

Comment: а как это проверить не подскажете?

Comment: Либо дебаг включать в консоли астериска (`sip set debug on`), либо утилитой tcpdump захватить пакеты в момент установления соединения и потом например wireshark просмотреть содержимое. И проверьте регистрации (`sip show registry`) и логи /var/log/asterisk/messages

Comment: Спасибо большое,после работы буду тестить.